# Watch parent scope, ng-include in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript

I'm trying to watch a parent property in my child module.

I have and html like this.

```
<div ng-include="maincontainer.selected"></div>
```

And in my maincontainer I have this:

```
class Maincontainer {
  var:string;
  scope: ng.IScope;
  selected: String;

  static $inject = ['$scope'];    

  constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
     this.scope = $scope;
     this.var = 'init';
     this.selected = "app/Views/ChildView.html";
  }
}
```

I want to watch in my ChildViewController the 'var' parent property.

```
class ChildView {
     scope: ng.IScope;

     static $inject = ['$scope'];

     constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
        this.scope = $scope;

        // Here I want to add a watch to the parent property.
     }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you try to `$watch`  `$parent.var`?

Comment: The problem is that typescript doen't recognize the name of the var and it doesn't transpile

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know TypeScript. But maybe [this](http://kenhowardpdx.com/blog/2015/05/how-to-watch-scope-properties-in-angular-with-typescript/) will help.

Comment: Thank you, but this link doesn't solve the problem of the parent scope, only for the own scope.

Answer (score 0):

To support the idea presented by Jahongir in the comments above...

You could create your own interface of what is being injected that will have all of $scope but allow $parent to be of any type:

```
interface IMyControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
  $parent: any;
}
```

and then declare $scope to be your new interface which defines var on $parent

```
constructor($scope: IMyControllerScope) {
```